# iPhone4 iOS5 ARC how to profile memory?

Tags: objective-c, memory, ios5, profiling, iphone-4

I'm trying to debug a mysterious app crash that happens after running the app for a few hours. 
My hunch is that this may be memory related, as I've not done any memory optimization since starting to build my app.

I'm looking at my application with the "allocations" instrument and I see these numbers:

```
All allocations 4.70mb
Living 51072
Transitory 357280
Overall Bytes 100.23mb
Overall 408000
```

**Which is the important number here?** Does my app take 4.7 Mb of memory or 100 Mb?  At which point should I be concerned about my app being killed for memory reasons? I want to avoid premature optimization :)

Since I'm using ARC and TabBarController, most of the controller related memory seems to be out of my hands, unless I find out how to create a tab and lazily init a controller when that tab is first touched.

Thank you!